# Best practice for handling an id being sent when performing a POST on an ApiController?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Consider the following two POST scenarios:

1. `POST /localhost/api/` - insert an entity, return 200
2. `POST /localhost/api/1324` - bad request, return 400

**What is the best way to deal with Scenario 2?**

Do I do nothing and assume developers using my API will understand this is wrong? Do I add code in my POST method to handle this and tell them this is a bad request?

I realise that returning a bad request is probably the best thing to do here, which is what I ended up implementing but I feel there might be a better way of achieving this that I haven't yet discovered.

My Current code is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyEntity entity) {
  if(entity.Id != null)
      throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

  MyEntity saved = repository.Insert(entity);

  HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, saved);
  response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, new Uri(saved.Id.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));

  return response;
}

// Prevents any attempt to POST with a Guid in the url
[HttpPost]
public void Post(Guid Id) {
  throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your doing seems valid. Although I have some doubts whether I would go to those lengths.

**Correction**

I had said

> If you hadn't implemented this this additional method then the routing
>   would have failed and would have normally returned a 404. I would be
>   tempted to leave it with this behavior.

But you are correct:

To get it to operate as above i.e. default to a 404, you would need the following route configurations:

```
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultCollectionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new { },
            constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) }
            );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {  },
            constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get, HttpMethod.Put, HttpMethod.Delete) }
            );
```

**To improve your existing approach slightly**

However, if you did feel the need to start policing the combination of verbs and routes then it may be worth moving this logic into an ActionFilterAttribute.

If you add this route at the top then it will en
Assuming you use `"id"` by convention for all routes you could quickly put together a filter that looked for a value in `RouteValues` with the key of `id` and raise a 400 exception.

```
public class ValidVerbAndRouteAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        object id;
        if (actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("id", out id) &&
            actionExecutedContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Post)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was having my doubts about the lengths I have went to myself -  however, if I was to leave out the second Post method, I would be able to add whatever garbage I wanted to the end of the url (i.e. `POST /localhost/api/blah1234`) and it would still hit the first Post method and continue as if the extra garbage wasn't there. It does not throw a 404 as you might expect.

Comment: I suppose the lack of 404 is due to my routeTemplete being `"api/{controller}/{id}"`. The API knows `{id}` is optional, so it would treat it as such and execute the first Post method in absence of the second.

Comment: @Stevie indeed. I have shown a way of altering that behavior using a route specific to collection based verbs, maybe worth trying.

Comment: That's perfect - I was literally just reading about Route constraints while you were making your edits. I'll have a go at implementing this and hopefully mark your answer correct in a few minutes! Edit: Worked as expected, thanks for your help Mark!

Answer (score 2):

The way you are handling it currently seems correct. It's standard input data validation and 400 is the correct status code to use if this validation fails in RESTful terms.

Comment: Actually, the HTTP code 405 (aka HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed) would be more appropriate. The accepted solution is definitely more elegant but I do not like the 404 code it produces. A proper RESTful API would return the 405 code. It would also output all the allowed HTTP methods in the "Allow" header when you call a URL using the OPTIONS method.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are tying to do it is correct, but there is another way for you to choose, if you would like to. You can configure your routes and state that there should be calls to concrete actions, than you can specify an action with a signature like

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostEntity([FromBody]MyEntity entity) {...}
```

which will make calls with any other signature for this action impossible and cause exception.

The routes:

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

And for exception handling I'd suggest an exception filter that contains a set of mappings of exception type and its' HttpStatusCode representation by your taste.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, but I'm aiming for RESTful API without Http Verbs in my urls.